# Convert UDF that Parses TIme-Starts to an Array formula

Tags: excel, vba, array-formulas

I created a UDF to parse time-starts from a delimited string.
- Returns an Array(0 to 23) that represent hours in the day
- Each time-start is separated by a comma
- `@` is used to signify multiple time-starts

For example `5@8p` returns 5 as the 20th element in the 0 based array.

> ```
> AssignmentList("2@12a,3@6a,10@12p,6p,5@8p")(0)
> ```

[image: Watch Window]

[image: Sample Data Set]

```
Sub Setup()
    Range("A1:AA1").Value = Array("1st", "2nd", "3rd", "12PM", "1AM", "2AM", "3AM", "4AM", "5AM", "6AM", "7AM", "8AM", "9AM", "10AM", "11AM", "12PM", "1PM", "2PM", "3PM", "4PM", "5PM", "6PM", "7PM", "8PM", "9PM", "10PM", "11PM")
    Range("A2:C2").Value = Array("12a", "10a,3@12p", "6p,5@8p")
    Range("D2:AA2").FormulaArray = "=AssignmentList($A2:$C2)"
End Sub

Function AssignmentList(ByRef Source As Variant) As Variant
    Dim Assignments(0 To 23) As Double
    Dim Item  As Variant, At As Variant
    Dim Text As String
    Text = WorksheetFunction.TextJoin(",", True, Source)

    For Each Item In Split(Text, ",")
        If InStr(Item, "@") > 0 Then
            At = Split(Item, "@")
            Assignments(Hour(At(1))) = Assignments(Hour(At(1))) + At(0)
        Else
            Assignments(Hour(Item)) = Assignments(Hour(Item)) + 1
        End If
    Next

    AssignmentList = Assignments
End Function
```

I would like to convert this function to an Array Formula but do not know where to start.  References or advice as where to start would be greatly appreciated.

I am also interested in anyway that I could improve my UDF.  Ultimately, I will use whichever function gives me the best performance.

Comment: What do you mean?  Your function returns an Array.  What would this conversion to an "Array formula" do differently?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I should have clarified my question.  I would like to replicate the functionality of my UDF using standard worksheet formulas.

Comment: So, your real question is: *"How do you do a loop in a native Excel formula?"* ?

Comment: @AJD Basically.  I've read post on using Sumproduct but I don't understand how to build the array.

Comment: I was thinking that the `5@8p` would be the difficult part. There are a couple of functions that would otherwise create the array (including INDEX/MATCH but there is another one that I cannot remember off the top of my head) for the other things.

Comment: and what about using VBA `Join` instead of a worksheet function?

Comment: @AJD The @ is very perplexing.  Range.Value returns a 2d array.  I would have to transpose it twice to convert it to a 1d array for Join().  Replacing TextJoin with a For Each loop maybe more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

- I would stick with the UDF -- it will be much simpler to maintain.
- I wouldn't bother with joining.
- I'd modify your routine a bit, but retain similar logic:
- Unless you will be dealing with fractions or very large numbers, I'd use Long instead of Double.

---

```
Function AssignmentList(Source) As Long()
    Dim Assignments(1 To 1, 1 To 24) As Long
    Dim I As Long, V As Variant, W As Variant
    Dim vSrc As Variant
    Dim t As Date, l As Long

vSrc = Source 'assumed to be a single horizontal row

For I = LBound(vSrc, 2) To UBound(vSrc, 2)
    V = Split(vSrc(1, I), ",")
    For Each W In V
        If InStr(W, "@") > 0 Then
            l = Split(W, "@")(0)
            t = Split(W, "@")(1)
        Else
            l = 1
            t = W
        End If
        Assignments(1, Hour(t) + 1) = l
    Next W
Next I

AssignmentList = Assignments

End Function
```

Comment: All valid points.  I am using `Double` because some of the assignments are 4 man crews which may include an extra person at times (e.g. `=4 *AssignmentList(...)` returns 5).

Comment: I would like to use worksheet functions if possible.  The workbook  is of `.xlsx`. format.  The problem is that it is uploaded into a system that I can not change.  I will probably go with the `UDF` and generate the `.xlsx`. Thanks